# Empty cell (inputs are numbers) coming up as 0 (VBA help!)

Tags: excel, is-empty, vba

I have three variables. (Dim a, b, c as Single)
I have all 3 set to values in a worksheet (percentages). When those values are cleared, I would like to see IsEmpty() = True for all three. However, c shows a 0 when empty and I can't figure a way to get it to show as an empty cell. The other two variables work just fine.

I'm assuming this is happening because VBA turns empty cells into 0's for cells with numbers as the designated inputs. What's the best way of finding empty cells for cases like this?

Comment: So instead of using IsEmpty, I used len(trim(c)) = 0 .. This seemed to not work either as c pointed to a "0", from what I understand, and the length > 0. If you skip the variable and use the cell reference...len(trim(cell reference)) then it comes out as a 0, aka empty cell.

Comment: When you do `Dim a, b, c As Single` then only `c` is a `Single` and `a` and `b` are `Variant`.